# Working with OSM Map API

Tags: android, maps

I am new to OSM Map API but I have already used the Google API for map. I want to render an OSM mapview and pin a pointer to the current location. how can I achieve that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSMDROID provides Tools / Views to interact with OpenStreetMap-Data.

The OpenStreetMapView is a (almost) full/free replacement for Androids MapView class.

[Download Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) .

Comment: @Maddy You have to check out the source code using svn . There they post svn link under Source Tab.

Comment: @Maddy Check this link for download source code using svn tortoise . http://stackoverflow.com/a/10598343/614807

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to reuse your code from Google Maps you can use the Google Maps Wrapper of OSM

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUseGoogleWrapper